# Minify make temp folder

Tags: php, minify

so i have the minify working on my site but it says

> Note: Please set $min_cachePath in /min/config.php to improve performance.

And in that folder i have this?

```
 /**
 * For best performance, specify your temp directory here. Otherwise Minify
 * will have to load extra code to guess. Some examples below:
 */
 //$min_cachePath = '/tmp';
 //$min_cachePath = preg_replace('/^\\d+;/', '', session_save_path());
```

so do i just make a folder named tmp and delete the // in front of the `//$min_cachePath = '/tmp';` and make it `$min_cachePath = '/tmp'`;

or do i have to add permissions to the file and add a text file in it too?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`/tmp` is a standard system directory (you don't mention it anywhere, but I'm going to assume you're using Linux or some other *nix).  It is writable by everyone, so all you need to do is uncomment that line (remove the leading //).

Comment: @ajreal, no, not necessarily, but in most typical configurations it is